# CSS box-shadow to appear on top child elements

Tags: html, css

I have an ul with an inset box-shadow:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #000;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #000;
```

I would like all the child elements to appear underneath this shadow.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jimsteinhart/XX36p/

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: i placed the wrong link to jsfiddle, this is the right one http://jsfiddle.net/jimsteinhart/XX36p/

Comment: do you want that the childs dont "touch" de shadow?

Comment: thanks for helping out, but it's fixed already. I editted the link in the original post also, thats why it was the same link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Position pseudo-element with shadow over the `ul`:

```
ul:before{
    content:''; width:100%; height:100%;
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #000;}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HvGGb/2/)

Comment: this doesn't seem to fix anything

Comment: I was a little bit too quick with my judgement... this works, see my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jimsteinhart/M88wS/

Thanks!

Comment: This gets the shadow there, but it blocks you from clicking anything under it.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is a solution ! with a pseudo-element and `pointer-events:none;`

```
ul:before{
  content:''; width:100%; height:100%;
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HvGGb/74/)